# Collapsible Panel from Right to Left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a jQuery collapsible panel from Right to Left but it's not working properly, when clicking to close and Highlight the active Link...

Please, find the link :

http://jsfiddle.net/egUHv/

and the code is :

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav').stop().animate({'marginRight':'-100px'},1000);

function toggleDivs() {
    var $inner = $("#nav");
    if ($inner.position().right == "-100px") {
        $inner.animate({right: 0});
        $(".nav-btn").html('<img src="images/slide-out.png" alt="open" />')
    }
    else {
        $inner.animate({right: "100px"}); 
        $(".nav-btn").html('<img src="images/slide-out.png" alt="close" />')
    }
}
$(".nav-btn").bind("click", function(){
    toggleDivs();
});

});
```

Comment: +1 for including a fiddle straight away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/egUHv/5/

```
$(function() {
$('#nav').stop().animate({'margin-right':'-100px'},1000);

function toggleDivs() {
var $inner = $("#nav");
if ($inner.css("margin-right") == "-100px") {
    $inner.animate({'margin-right': '0'});
    $(".nav-btn").html('<img src="images/slide-out.png" alt="open" />')
}
else {
    $inner.animate({'margin-right': "-100px"}); 
    $(".nav-btn").html('<img src="images/slide-out.png" alt="close" />')
}
}
$(".nav-btn").bind("click", function(){
    toggleDivs();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery's .position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) does not return an object with a `right` property so your current code always go in the `else` condition (since `$inner.position().right === undefined !== '-100px'`).

`.position()` returns an object with `left` and `top` properties.

Here's a solution using class toggle on the `#nav` element to determine if the nav is closed/opened instead of checking the position of the element:

```
$(function() {
  $('#nav')
    .stop()
    .animate({'marginRight':'-100px'},1000, function() { $(this).addClass('closed'); });

  function toggleDivs() {
    var $inner = $("#nav");
    var $img = $(".nav-btn img", $inner);

    if ($inner.hasClass('closed')) {
      $inner.animate({ right: "100px" }); 
      $img.attr('alt', 'close');
    } else {
      $inner.animate({ right: 0 });
      $img.attr('alt', 'open');
    }

    $inner.toggleClass('closed');
  }

  $(".nav-btn").bind("click", function() {
    toggleDivs();
  });
});
```